# Filter feed by keywords with Yahoo pipes

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I want to create a filter based on a couple of keywords. Let's say we have two keywords, water and sand then I like to create a filter that searches for both keywords in the description. So both water and sand should exist in the description. Can anyone guide me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use a simple filter (under operators) with multiple rules for each keyword and select permit items that match any?